# How to use variable outside the main window class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ShelfMapping.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Shelf Mapping" Height="800" Width="1320"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded" Unloaded="Window_Unloaded">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="camera" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="10,10,662,279" />

        <Image Name="depthOut"  Height="480"  Width="640" Margin="667,10,5,289"/>
        <Canvas Name="canvas" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="667,10,5,289"/>
        <Button Content="Screenshot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="298,649,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonScreenshotClick"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="101" Margin="901,514,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223"/>
        <Button Content="OCR" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="486,649,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.205,0.304" Click="click_OCR"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my XAML code. I want to use the `canvas` variable outside the main window class. I don't know how to use that variable outside `MainWindow.cs`.

Comment: Outside as in? Window itself is the main container of your controls. How do you call this window?

Comment: In another class i want to use the variable 'canvas'.

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing the window's contents from outside of the window.  Let it encapsulate its contents from external entities.

Comment: As @Servy said, if you need to do this, then it's probably a sign that something is wrong with your design. Look up MVVM to get a better understanding of how to structure your code. Your canvas is part of the view and should be needed outside of that view. If you *absolutely have to have it*, then you'll need a public property in your `MainWindow` class that will expose it.

Comment: The design warnings are real and should be considered, but if one way is to have a property on the other class you want and register the control on it.   public TextBoxMainWindow { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Non fancy way 1:

`xaml` *(x)* namespace has property for it:

```
x:FieldModifier="public"
```

so your code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" x:FieldModifier="public" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="667,10,5,289"/>
```

now if you have an Instance of `MainWindow`, you could access to this `canvas`.

### Non fancy way 2:

Create a public property in MainWindow.cs codebehind

```
public Canvas Canvas { get { return cica; } }
```

(maybe a static if you wanna be really dirty)

---

*ps.: Comments are right. You have problem with your design*

Answer (score 0):

I've just created an example for a little practice. I not sure if it fits here exactly because i don't know what you want to accomplish by accessing the canvas. Anyway let's get to work:

An example of a ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public ICommand ChangeWidthCommand { get; set; }

    public int CanvasWidth
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CanvasWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CanvasWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CanvasWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CanvasWidth", typeof(int), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ChangeWidthCommand = new ChangeWidthCommand(this);
    }
}
```

The simple command is right here:

```
public class ChangeWidthCommand : ICommand
{
    ViewModel vm { get; set; }

    public ChangeWidthCommand(ViewModel _vm)
    {
        vm = _vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        vm.CanvasWidth += 10;
    }
}
```

And this could be your Canvas definition:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="drawSplice" Width="{Binding CanvasWidth}" Height="200"  Background="SlateBlue">
    <Canvas.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Canvas.DataContext>
    <Button Content="Change width" Command="{Binding ChangeWidthCommand}" Canvas.Top="220" Canvas.Left="-30"/>
</Canvas>
```

So what exactly am i doing here? Just accessing the canvas outside the Window class via that custom Command in order to change its width when the button it's clicked.

Not a big deal indeed, just send the model as a reference to the command. You may choose define some delegates inside the Command class implementation and send method names as params in the constructor.

I think that would be it for tonight. Have fun !